# Uploading images from CSV to datagridview to database

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, datagridview

Hi i would like to know how do i use use image from CSV file to a datagridview to a database?

```
 OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.DefaultExt = ".csv";
        ofd.Filter = "Comma Separated (*.csv)|*.csv";
        // ofd.ShowDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtFileName.Text = ofd.FileName;

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            string filePath = txtFileName.Text;
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
            string[] totalData = new string[System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Length];
            totalData = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(',');

            foreach (string dataItem in totalData)
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add(dataItem);
            }

            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                totalData = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(',');
                dataTable.Rows.Add(totalData);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
        }
```

This are the codes i use for browsing the csv file into the datagridview but i am not sure if those codes will cause a problem for the image.^

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[22].Value);
```

This is the line of code that is suppose to upload image from datagridview to the database but the error message shows that the uploading is not in the right format.^

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Normally pictures are not in csv files as they are text - are you sure of the format?

Comment: hi i googled and they mentioned that it is possible to store image information in CSV files

Comment: please give example of your csv because csv does imply text - it is technically possible to convert your image to ascii type storage but you;d need to know how it was done and it wouldnt be just assign value to image

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
    SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[22].Value != null)
                        param.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[22].Value;
    else
                        param.Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Try to set dbtype may be because of undefining dbtype it cause error

Comment: If it _is_ an image, and _if_ that image has been encoded into something textual, then this seems unlikely to work.  You would need to first convert it into something that is binary.  Such as `Convert.FromBase64String(value)`.  But that means you need to know what the encoding is...this is just the most likely candidate.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I think its something got to do with Bitmap property from my research...